# Using AutoMapper in POCO?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, poco, automapper, business-logic

I currently have a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) class in my ASP.NET MVC project that handles all business logic.  There are no references to other projects or third-party assemblies.

I am also using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) in my other projects to facilitate mapping between view models / entities.  It is a fantastic tool and saves me considerable time when I make changes to fields on a given entity.

However, within my POCO class are a few segments of code that map between entities.  The business purpose is to take entities from one data source and update another data source.  Here I am manually mapping and I'm finding it annoying to go in and adjust that mapping when I could employ AutoMapper instead.

Is it a good idea or a bad idea to use AutoMapper in my business logic project?  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'll respond to your question with a question.

**Why would it ever be bad to use AutoMapper to map properties?**  I cannot think of a reason, besides a concern over taking an external assembly reference, that you would not want to use AutoMapper.

Comment: I was hoping that was the case - just wasn't entirely confident.  Thanks!